# linux + timeout from command

Tags: linux, redhat, lvm, timeout

in my bash script I want to add timeout for the lvresize command
so if the command is waiting ,

I will exit after 5 second , as the follwing:

```
 timeout 5  lvresize -L 1M /dev/mapper/rootvg-home

 Rounding size to boundary between physical extents: 32.00 MiB
 WARNING: Reducing active and open logical volume to 32.00 MiB
 THIS MAY DESTROY YOUR DATA (filesystem etc.)
 Do you really want to reduce home? [y/n]:
```

but from some unclear reason timeout not works on lvresize?

why? timeout not exit the command after 5 sec?

Comment: Killing a command that's modifying a logical volume with a (probably mounted) filesystem seems like a good way to corrupt the volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whyever this fails (my assumption would be `lvresize` ignoring the `TERM` signal), this a terrible approach, as `lvresize`'s real task might take that long and you really don't want to kill it while it works.

Instead, ask for confirmation separately (with `timeout` if need be) and then run `lvresize` uninterrupted.

Comment: is it possible to tell lvresize for answering by default as NO ?

Comment: As the man page says (`man lvresize`), you can pass `--force`, but again, this is a really good way to corrupt your filesystem if you don't fully understand what you're doing.  I suggest learning `expect` if you really want to resize volumes or filesystems in a script.

Answer (score 0):

To answer no to any question add `-qq` option to a command.

When using `--force/--yes` you should double check what is the script doing. +1 to Karen B's suggestion to use `expect`.